# Trying to get search bar to display when you click button?

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is, that when the user clicks on the search button, the search bar displays. But for some reason, it's just not working and I have no idea, why? I double-checked on
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp just to make sure I am doing it right but to no avail. I tried the  `add.eventlistner`  that does not work, because it sees the button as null where the `onclick="showBar()"` should see the button, in JS.

HTML

```html
<button onclick="showBar()" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
  Search
  <img src="./images/iconmonstr-search-thin-240.png" alt="search icon">
</button>
```

CSS

```css
.form-control, .me-2 {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.me-2 {
  display: none !important;
}
```

JS

```js
let slideSearch = document.querySelector(".me-2");

function showBar() {
  slideSearch.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser dev-tools console? I also highly recommend using `type="button"` unless you actually want that button to submit forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `!important` on `display: none` of `.me-2`.

You should not use `!important` in your style unless you want to hide it permanently.

```js
let slideSearch = document.querySelector(".me-2");

function showBar() {
  slideSearch.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.form-control, .me-2 {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.me-2 {
  display: none; /*Removed !important*/
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showBar()" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
  Search
  <img src="./images/iconmonstr-search-thin-240.png" alt="search icon">
</button>
<input class="me-2"/>
```

If you cannot get rid of `!important` for some reason. You can try to add `!important` to `.me-2` in Javascript that would override `!important` in your CSS.

```js
let slideSearch = document.querySelector(".me-2");

function showBar() {
  slideSearch.style.setProperty('display','block','important');
}
```

```css
.form-control, .me-2 {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.me-2 {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showBar()" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
  Search
  <img src="./images/iconmonstr-search-thin-240.png" alt="search icon">
</button>
<input class="me-2"/>
```